# How to set bash environment variables using lua

Tags: lua, environment-variables

I am new to lua script features.
I tried using,

1. os.execute("export MY_VAR=10")
2. io.popen("export MY_VAR=10")

from lua script.

I try reading MY_VAR variable from shell using echo $MY_VAR after lua script is executed but I do not see MY_VAR getting set to 10.

How do we set the environment variable using lua script?

Comment: One workaround you can do is to have the Lua code output the contents of a Bash script and then have bash "source" or "eval" that script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem isn't a lua problem. Your problem is misunderstanding how process environments work.

Every time you run `os.execute` or `io.popen` you are running a **new** process with  **new** environment.

So while you may be correctly setting `MY_VAR` in that processes environment (and it would affect any processes run as children processes of *that* process) it doesn't survive beyond the death of the launched process and so cannot be seen by any other processes.

If you want to affect the `lua` process's environment (which would then, in turn, affect the environment's of processes run by lua) then you need a binding to the `setenv` system function (which lua itself doesn't provide as it doesn't pass the *clean* C test that lua uses for things it includes).

Comment: Yes. There is a `setenv` binding in luaposix: http://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/modules/posix.stdlib.html#setenv

Comment: @DougCurrie Documentation states that `Set an environment variable for this process. (Child processes will inherit this)`... How about the other processes ? Is it persistent?