# Set shell environment variable in a Lua 5.3 script

Tags: lua, environment-variables

Windows - embedded instance of Lua - shared environment only - recent changes to the language.

Results of Lua scripts need to be made available to the Windows host application of an embedded Lua 5.3 interpreter. Mostly we write the results to textfiles or the clipboard and let the host read those after the script finishes. Another method would be to set an envar (environment variable) in the current environment that host and interpreter share. It would eliminate the fileIO and some string-copy operations.

Lua has `os.getenv()` but no `os.setenv()` since the latter is not part of ANSI-C. External modules that claim to be able to alter environment variables seem to alter a local copy of it in `_G`, not the true host's current environment. (Since I haven't read all sources I'm judging those books by their cover here.) Moreover, since version 5.3 the global variable `_G` no longer exists, which I assume to mean that the majority of those modules will not be compatible with the current version of Lua.

**Question**: Which module allows changing variables in the current environment and is compatible with Lua 5.3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set bash environment variables using lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907930/how-to-set-bash-environment-variables-using-lua)

Comment: The first line summarizes four points on which my question is different.

Comment: can try my https://github.com/moteus/lua-environ. But it does not allow change environment for some foreign process. Only for current process.

Comment: A child process cannot change its parent's environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setenv](http://stevedonovan.github.io/winapi/api.html#setenv) from winapi module to change the environment of the current process (it is using [SetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206(v=vs.85).aspx) internally).

Comment: This function has problem with buffer overflow. I report about this i think about 4 years ago. Test case `setenv('xxxx', ('1'):rep(1300)`